# Using JQuery in Node server - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, typescript

I need to do an ajax call from node server using `TypeScript`.
I am importing `jquery` as below to my class

```
import * as $ from "jquery"
```

if I hover over my implementation, it recognizes the ajax as below

[image]

Then, I compile this TypeScript to JavaScript. It is successful.

If I host the node server and try to access this function I am getting below error

```
TypeError : $.ajax is not a function.
```

I think I am missing something. I am unable to figure the things out.

Comment: Using jQuery from Node makes no sense.  You should use a server-side HTTP client, such as Axios or Request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't do this; jQuery is for the client side, not the server**

As mentioned in comments, You should use a server-side HTTP client, such as the built in [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) method, or a library such as `npm-fetch` or Axios as your needs might dictate.

---

However, assuming you're using the `jquery` npm package, please note the following quote from the [package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery):

> For jQuery to work in Node, a window with a document is required. Since no such window exists natively in Node, one can be mocked by tools such as jsdom.

What the npm package provides is a factory for instantiating jQuery injected with a faked `window`. They give an example of how to do that, but this part is pretty revealing:

> This can be useful for testing purposes.

"For testing purposes" means purposes such as running unit tests in nodejs as part of your build pipeline for a client side package. Not as a general purpose library for use in node.

Comment: ...and if you do want to use jquery for HTML parsing and traversal in node, you're better off with [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/), which has the same API as jquery, but a much faster DOMless implementation for the server.